How to run Looker assertion for data quality tests? on non-imuable data
I'm currently working on a project where I need to validate data quality assertions in Looker.
The data is mirrored in a PostgreSQL database, and it changes frequently (at least once a day), which can potentially affect the metric values I need to assert (deletion).
Goal: Validate Looker assertion test to ensure data quality.
Problem: I need to update the assertion values dynamically before running the tests because the data can change frequently, which might alter the metric values.
Idea:

Run queries on source tables in Bigquery to retrieve the current assertion values.
Update the assertion values in Looker at the time of running the test, in the CI.
Trigger Looker assertion tests via API calls (using spectacle) in the CI.
Validate the test results.

Questions:

Is this a good approach to update the test values "on the fly" in a CI/CD pipeline?
Are there any best practices or alternative methods to achieve this in a more efficient way?
How can I ensure the accuracy and reliability of the assertions when the data changes frequently?

Thanks !

Is there no part of the tables of interest that do not change over time? If it's transactional data (eg sales and orders tables), maybe old orders don't change after a certain point that you can use in data test?
